# how to get data within the callback function of an ajax function using jquery?

Tags: jquery

As the best option for getting return data from an ajax call was to use a function. In my case below, I called the function returnData() but how do I get this outside this returnData() function?

```
           var testFile = $("#selection").val(),
           testData = getTestData(testFile); 

           function getTestData(testF) {
           $.getJSON("test.php", {
           fileTest: testF
           }, function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                if (value != "") {} else {
                 testArray[index] = value;
               }
           });
       });
         returnData(testArray);
      } ​
```

Comment: Why not process the data right in the callback?

Comment: Perhaps he wants to set it as a global or he wants to repeatedly read that values from many locations? I would usually process it in the callback as you have suggested, though.

Comment: Note : `returnData(testArray);` may or may not be executed BEFORE `testArray[index] = value;` due to the asynchronous nature of ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = null;

result = getTestData();

function getTestData(){
    return returnData(testArray);
}

alert(result);
```

By the way, where was testArray defined in the first place? It seems from your code it was already defined outside of `getTestData()`.

Also, the code behind callback will probably be executed before the AJAX function returns:

```
var noodleIsCooked = false;

$.post("cook.php", {"Start cooking"}, function(){
    noodleIsCooked = true;
});

eatNoodle();

function eatNoodle(){
    if(!noodleIsCooked){
        alert("Yike I can't eat this!");
    }
}
```

The above code will almost always fire the alert.

However, to eat cooked noodle, you need to put the `eatNoodle()` within the callback like this:

```
$.post("cook.php", {"Start cooking"}, function(){
        noodleIsCooked = true;
        eatNoodle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside of the functions.

```
var testFile = $("#selection").val(),
    results = '', // We will store the results in this
    testData = getTestData(testFile); 

function returnData(valueReturned)
{
  results = valueReturned; // Store the results into that variable we created
  anotherFunction();
}

function getTestData(testF) {
    $.getJSON("test.php", {
        fileTest: testF
    }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            if (value != "") {} else {
                testArray[index] = value;
            }
        });
    });
  returnData(testArray);
}​

function anotherFunction(){
  // We can access the contents of the results variable here :)
  console.log(results); 
}
```